# Loop through folders in Python and for files containing strings

Tags: python

I am very new to python. 
I need to iterate through the subdirectories of a given directory and return all files containing a certain string.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".sql")):
            if 'gen_dts' in open(name).read():
                print name
```

This was the closest I got.

The syntax error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#77>", line 4, in <module>
    if 'gen_dts' in open(name).read():
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dq_offer_desc_bad_pkey_vw.sql'
```

The 'dq_offer_desc_bad_pkey_vw.sql' file does not contain 'gen_dts' in it.

I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: At first glance it looks like this works.  What is the result?

Comment: The error I get is  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#77>", line 4, in <module>
    if 'gen_dts' in open(name).read():
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dq_offer_desc_bad_pkey_vw.sql'

Comment: @user3264602, you should edit your question to include that error; it helps a lot in answering. I'm writing an answer now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're trying to open `name`, which is just the file's *name*, not it's full relative path. What you need to do is `open(os.path.join(root, name), 'r')` (I added the mode since it's good practice).

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('.sql'):
            filepath = os.path.join(root, name)
            if 'gen_dts' in open(filepath, 'r').read():
                print filepath
```

`os.walk()` returns a generator that gives you tuples like `(root, dirs, files)`, where `root` is the current directory, and `dirs` and `files` are the names of the directories and files, respectively, that are in the root directory. Note that they are the *names*, not the paths; or to be precise, they're the path of that directory/file *relative* to the current root directory, which is another way of saying the same thing. Another way to think of it is that the directories and files in `dirs` and `files` will never have slashes in them.

One final point; the root directory paths always begin with the path that you pass to `os.walk()`, whether it was relative to your current working directory or not. So, for `os.walk('three')`, the `root` in the first tuple will be `'three'` (for `os.walk('three/')`, it'll be `'three/'`). For `os.walk('../two/three')`, it'll be `'../two/three'`. For `os.walk('/one/two/three/')`, it'll be `'/one/two/three/'`; the second one might be `'/one/two/three/four'`.

Answer (score 0):

The files are just the file names. You need to add the path to the before opening them. Use os.path.join.